initialisation error from json in Pydantic
Help with pydantic usage in python. my code ->
from typing import Any, List, Optional, Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic_core import from_json

class Check1UnitValidator(BaseModel):
    field_name: str
    restricted_values: List[str]
    action: Literal["Reject", "Underreview", "NA"]

class Check1Validator(BaseModel):
    check1_units: Any #List[Check1UnitValidator]

with open('BRE/utils/check1.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
check1 = Check1Validator(from_json(data))

print(check1)

My above code is giving error.
Error:
check1 = Check1Validator(from_json(data))
TypeError: init() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
json file:
{
    "check1_units": [
        {
            "field_name": "pincode",
            "restricted_values": [
                "123456",
                "456789"
            ],
            "action": "Reject"
        }
    ]
}

How do i resolve this??
I don't know what i am doing wrong? why does init is taking 2 args?
I am just passing the only 1 argument, i am not able to catch what is wrong. It should work fine my python version is 3.8.12 and pydantic version is 2.7.
I tried without using json file and using dict its working but whats wrong with this?

What is from_json? Why not doing it with model_validate_json as the documentation says?
